# About template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, template-specialization

I need to provide an insertion/lookup/delete interface for a hash table. I wrote the hash table only to provide the internal bucket/entry management. The hash function should be supplied from outside. I am now stuck on how to expose the interface so that the hash table can handle byte arrays as well as fixed length data types. The problem is that for byte arrays, the hash function needs to know the length of the array while for other types, it can do without that information. My problems is that I can't implement `operator[]` for byte arrays because the hash function needs two parameters. And I would like to keep `operator[]` dearly. Is there any way around this (Without specializing for `T*` and throwing a compiler error for `operator[]` in that specialization.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting confused here because I don't get where operator[] on the hash-table conflicts with operator[] on the data-type that you are storing in it.

If your hash_table has operator[] this could either be a hash_map where you supply the key to operator[] or it could be that operator[] returns you the contents of a cell.

Normally if I do implement my own hash-table I do not directly store the data in the entries but the data plus some "metadata", i.e. info relating to the cell. As your hash-table supports delete you need to ensure that you can still reach any collisions that presumably were moved elsewhere, whatever your strategy now is for finding such a cell. So a deleted cell is available but has a different meaning to one that has never been occupied, as it may be part of a path in a collision course.

The hash function is independent, as you say. It is independent therefore of the storage mechanism, and does not call operator[] of the hash-table at all.

The hash-table uses the hash-function and a comparison function only, and otherwise uses its own storage policy and collision-handling policy.

Comment: +1. I guess the hash table should not be aware of the byte layout of the key. I will implement a wrapper class for byte array keys.

Answer (score 0):

> can handle byte arrays as well as fixed length data types

So, your byte arrays vary in size.  You'll need to record the length of each somewhere.  If you want to store them in the hash table by value, then you can package up the data and a length value in an object: the STL already provides some classes suitable for this including std::vector<> and std::string<>.  Alternatively, if you only want the hash table to store pointers/references to your byte arrays, then you can create a trivial "handle" class that either stores or knows where to find the length, and has a pointer/reference to the data.

As "CashCow" points out, there is no inherent conflict between `operator[]` on the byte array and that on the hash table... they can even be chained if necessary.